# It is ok using a Price with 0USD as a Free Tier in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building the subscription functionality for my app and I was wondering what would be the best way of handling the free tier subscription.

If someone downgrades to the free tier, should I change his/her subscription to a 0USD Price or should I cancel his/her subscription?

I can't find any suggestion anywhere.

Comment: If you'd like to keep tracking the users's subscription for accounting or reporting purposes a 0 dollar price seems reasonable, you could also consider applying a 100% coupon for the duration of free service. Cancelling and bringing them back onto a Subscription is also possible.

Comment: Thanks @v3nkman, I'm probably going to use it then and see how it works